# Laravel Ajax Request is Empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a toggle button, which will change the status (Show/Hide).
I am sending proper data in ajax and try to consol and it shows correct data but in the controller, the request is empty. I have added CSRF token already and it is not the token issue. I don't know why?
Here is my complete code:

```
$status_btn = '<div class="form-check form-switch ps-0 bg-primary ms-auto my-auto">
            <input class="form-check-input ms-auto mt-1' . ($firmware->status == 1 ? ' bg-primary ' : '') . '" type="checkbox" data-id="' . $firmware->id . '" id="status_update" ' . ($firmware->status == 1 ? "checked" : "") . '>
                </div>';
```

This is my Jquery AJAX code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#status_update', function(e) {
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                $(this).addClass('bg-primary border-2');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('bg-primary');
            }
            var data = {
                id: $(this).data('id'),
                status: $(this).prop('checked') == true ? 1 : 0,
            };
            var url = "{{ route('changeFirmwareStatus') }}";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: data,
                dataType: "json",
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(response) {
                    toastr.options = {
                        "closeButton": true,
                        "progressBar": true,
                        "showDuration": 300,
                        "timeOut": 2000,
                        "hideDuration": 1000,
                        // "preventDuplicates": true,
                    }
                    toastr[response.state](response.message);
                }
            });

        });
```

This is my controller Route:

```
Route::post('/changeFirmwareStatus', [FirmwareController::class, 'changeFirmwareStatus'])->name('changeFirmwareStatus');
```

This is my controller code:

```
public function changeFirmwareStatus(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
    $firmware = Firmware::findOrFail($request->id);

    $firmware->update(['status' => $request->status]);

    if ($firmware == true) {
        return $this->JsonResponse(200, 'success', 'Firmware Status Successfully Changed !');
    } else {
        return $this->JsonResponse(422, 'error', 'Something Went Wrong !');
    }
}
```

Take a look and guide me, (I do not want GET method and query string). Thanks in Advance

Comment: Does `data` contains anything? did you `console.log()` ?

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is these two lines in your ajax code

```
processData: false,
contentType: false,
```

These are typically added when using `FormData`. But you are currently sending json data. So you can remove these two lines and it should work. Cheers